# Tennis court booking rules

Tags: simulation

This does seem oddly out of place, but bear with me....
If we have 3 courts, and 150 members, how can we simulate the effects of changing booking rules? For example if we can currently book 7 times per week but can only "hold" up to four live bookings, and I propose to change that to 7 bookings?

How can I model the changes if we kept the ability to hold 4 bookings, but allowed members to book up to a month in advance instead of just a week?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Flude, welcome to the community. Assume we know nothing. Explain what you are doing today, and people who read your description will try and think of solutions from their own vantage point

Comment: You could probably try one of the software used for rotas like: https://www.optaplanner.org/ or http://www.abc-roster.com/ and define constraints based on your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: FLude, just reword your question and it will be re-opened. State that you are seeking simulation software, then say what you want to simulate and what variables there are - it's all in your question, but it needs to be reworded to ask for a s/w recommendation (at the moment, it reads like you are looking for an algorithm or mathematical formula). [Ask] should Help. Welcome aboard, and good luck. We really do want to help you :-)